# How Control actually moves inside a Laravel Application?

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller

In an interview, the interviewer asked me this question that how control moves in laravel after we hit URL in our browser. Suppose a web application built on laravel is running and I need to access its web pages, So how the request transmits within the laravel application hosted on the server.I told him that it is

```
Routes -> Controller -> Views (for static pages)
```

But this is not the correct order.Even google has very less number of search results on this topic.Can anyone please explain the exact sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look this [Laravel-architecture](http://laravelbook.com/laravel-architecture/) link

[image]

Comment: I think that's right for a basic laravel app, and an interview question. I'd possibly expand `3. Model` to be `Application` - which could include any amount of application logic, model / database calls, api calls, etc.

Comment: And maybe for an interview, mention that it is common to abstract model and database logic from a controller to a repository class